# how to add multiple functions in matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to add several functions from a single .m file. Is this possible without actually having to create an individual m file for each function?

Comment: Duplicate: [Is it possible to define more than one function per file in MATLAB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3569933/is-it-possible-to-define-more-than-one-function-per-file-in-matlab).

Answer (score 10):

For later versions of Matlab that support the `classdef` keyword, I recommend adding the functions as static methods to a class and then calling them from an instance of that class. It can all be done with one .m file:

```
classdef roof
  methods (Static)
    function res = f1(...)
        ...
    end
    function res = f2(...)
        ...
    end
  end
end
```

and you call them by

```
roof.f1();
roof.f2();
```