# In MATLAB, can I have a script and a function definition in the same file?

Tags: file, matlab, function

Suppose I have a function `f()` and I want to use it in `my_file.m`, which is a script.

1. Is it possible to have the function defined in `my_file.m`?
2. If not, suppose I have it defined in `f.m`. How do I call it in `my_file.m`?

I read the online documentation, but it wasn't clear what is the best way to do this.

Comment: Note that you can put functions in scripts in Octave.

Comment: Consider this answer for ways to organize your code http://stackoverflow.com/a/3569946/18775

Comment: Very recommend to take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17315586/matlab-is-there-a-function-which-echo-text-of-file?noredirect=1#comment25114932_17315586

Comment: The real question should be: Who at Mathworks do I complain to to get this ridiculous bug fixed?

Comment: As of MATLAB 2016b, functions can be defined in scripts. I am not sure why they waited 32 years to add this fairly basic feature.

Answer (score 50):

As of release R2016b, you can have [local functions in scripts](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/local-functions-in-scripts.html), like so:

```
data = 1:10;            % A vector of data
squaredData = f(data);  % Invoke the local function

function y = f(x)
  y = x.^2;
end
```

Prior to release R2016b, the only [type of function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/types-of-functions.html) that could be defined inside a MATLAB script was an [anonymous function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html). For example:

```
data = 1:10;            % A vector of data
f = @(x) x.^2;          % An anonymous function
squaredData = f(data);  % Invoke the anonymous function
```

Note that anonymous functions are better suited to simple operations, since they have to be defined in a single expression. For more complicated functions, you will have to define them in their own files, [place them somewhere on the MATLAB path](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/what-is-the-matlab-search-path.html) to make them accessible to your script, and then call them from your script as you would any other function.

Answer (score 38):

The way I get around this limitation, is to turn my scripts into functions that take no arguments (if I need variables from the global namespace, I either explicitly pass them in the function, or use "evalin" to grab them.)

Then you can define all the additional functions you need in the "script."  It's a hack, but I have found it to be quite powerful in those cases where I need several non-trivial functions.

EDIT:  Here's a simplistic example.  All this can reside in a single file.

```
function [] = myScriptAsAFunction()
   img = randn(200);
   img = smooth(img);
   figure(1);
   imagesc(img);
   axis image;
   colorbar;
end

function simg = smooth(img)
    simg = img / 5;
end
```

Comment: +1, it really annoys me when I see clear all; close all; at the top of a matlab script. If you have so many variables and plots floating around you can't keep track of them you're not using enough functions.

Comment: Can you please include a sample implementation of this "hack"? I can't seem to figure out how this works.

Comment: Note one problem with this approach is that the variables never make it into your workspace when the function exits. This can be a problem if you want to play/look/use those variables upon the end of the script.

Comment: @chessofnerd When I have the problem, I either return the variables in the function output, or I use assignin.

Comment: @John, I personally feel that is a bit of a pain to have to return all variables individually as opposed to having them show up in the work space on their own. That said, I had never heard of `assignin`. That is a neat function that I might be using more!

Comment: @chessofnerd I have recently adopted the practice of returning complex outputs of a function in a structure.  This has cleaned up my parameter lists immensely and makes interfaces much more "future proof."

Answer (score 20):

You can do something like this (assuming your file is named `my_file.m`):

```
function my_file
   %script here
end

function out = f(in)
   %function here
end
```

If you click the run button the function `my_file` will be executed as default.

Comment: Is this different from the answer by John?

Answer (score 7):

1) You cannot nest a function inside a script.

2) Make sure f.m is on your path or in current directory, and you can call it like any other function.

Comment: You can nest a function inside a script if you follow what is proposed by @Oneiros. You can even call your function (`f` in his example) from within your script (`my_file` in his example).

Answer (score 7):

[As of R2016b](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/local-functions-in-scripts.html), you can define local functions within a script.

```
x = 1;
y = add1(x);

function z = add1(x)
    z = x + 1;
end
```

Answer (score 3):

I have implemented [the solution by John](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9166784/2707864), and I found it useful. But there are a couple of caveats (in Octave; Matlab possibly behaves similarly):

1. If code inside your main function contains `clear all` prior to using the auxiliary function, it will not work. In file `test3.m`, commenting/uncommenting `clear all` makes code work/not work.

   ```
   function [] = test3()
     %clear all
     a = myfunc( 1 );
     a
   endfunction;

   %---------------------------------
   % Auxiliary functions

   function retval = myfunc( a )
     retval = 2 * a;
   endfunction;
   ```

   From  It seems like upon running a script, there is a first pass where code outside functions is executed (in this case, there is no such code), and functions defined (in this case, `test3` and `myfunc`) are added to the workspace. A second pass would execute the main function, which would not find `myfunc` if `clear all` is active.
2. As pointed out by chessofnerd, out-of-the-box the variables in your main function do not go to the workspace.

Answer (score 2):

You can have many functions in a sample file. But only the first one can act as a main function, when you run the file. Others can be used merely in this file. For some situation you want to define a big function. You can separate it into smaller functions and define below it.

However, the most simple way to find the answer is having a try~