# MATLAB script code and function code in the same file?

Tags: matlab, syntax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In MATLAB, can I have a script and a function definition in the same file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5363397/in-matlab-can-i-have-a-script-and-a-function-definition-in-the-same-file)

Can I have MATLAB script code and function code in the same file?

```
%% SAVED IN FILE myfunc.m (otherwise fail)
function [out1] = myfunc( x )
out1 = sqrt( 1 + (cos(x))^2 );
end

%%
%OTHER CRAP
y = 1:10
% use myfunc
```

It doesn't seem to work, even with the `end` keyword there.  Is this type of thing allowed or do I always need to have EACH function in its own properly named file?

I'm sure I saw functions and code that uses those functions in the same file a couple years ago.

Comment: Its not a duplicate, that question asks something different and is actually a lot more vague than what I'm asking here.

Comment: Although the other question is not very well written/formatted, both questions ask the same thing: if you can combine a script and a function definition in the same file.

Comment: Yeah so close that one not this one

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If m-code has a function in it, all the code must be encapsulated by functions. **The name of the entry-point function should match the filename**. If you think about it, this makes sense because it favors code re-use.

You can try this:

filename: myScript.m

```
function [] = myScript()
 y = 1:10;
 out1 = myfunc(y);
end

function [out1] = myfunc( x )
 out1 = sqrt( 1 + (cos(x))^2 );
end
```

Then you can either hit F5, or from the matlab command prompt type myScript

Comment: The entry-point function _should_ match the filename, but the language does not enforce it. If it differs, Matlab will use the filename as the name of the function, ignoring the "function" line. It's a warning in mlint.

Comment: Thanks, I replaced must with should.

Answer (score 3):

[rossb83's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5394494/matlab-script-code-and-function-code-in-the-same-file/5394558#5394558) is correct, and just to extend that, you should know that [functions can have subfunctions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f4-70666.html):

```
function sum = function myMath(a, b)
    foo = a + b;
    bar = mySubFunc(foo);
end

function bar = mySubFunc(foo)
    bar = foo^2;
end
```

Comment: Stored in `myMath.m`.  So you're saying any other function other than the "primary" function is considered a subfunction