# matlab - is there a function which echo text of file ?

Tags: matlab

Since it is not possible to [have a script and a function definition in the same file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5363397/in-matlab-can-i-have-a-script-and-a-function-definition-in-the-same-file) , I thought to echo the function which I want to attach in the script such that I get a script with function code and then some usage with this function .

For example  -

**func1.m**

```
function [result] = func1(x)
    result=sqrt(x) ;  
end
```

**script1.m**

```
echo(func1.m) ; 
display(func1(9))
```

Desire output for **script1.m**

```
function [result] = func1(x)
        result=sqrt(x) ;  
    end
display(func1(9)) 
3
```

Have you any idea for that ?

Comment: -1: why on earth would you want to do this? Other than classroom use I really don't see how this could be useful, and even there; why not just open the editor?

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis : you right  ,  it's for classroom use  - I should write a function and then show how I used it  , so I create a script which I write it  `type` of the function then some usage with this function and finally export all its output into pdf using `publish` option .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since a convoluted solution was already proposed, why not stating the obvious?

Matlab has a built-in command that does exactly what you want. It is called **`type`**:

```
>> type('mean')
```

will give you this:

```
function y = mean(x,dim)
%MEAN   Average or mean value.
%   For vectors, MEAN(X) is the mean value of the elements in X. For
%   matrices, MEAN(X) is a row vector containing the mean value of
%   each column.  For N-D arrays, MEAN(X) is the mean value of the
%   elements along the first non-singleton dimension of X.
%
%   MEAN(X,DIM) takes the mean along the dimension DIM of X. 
%
%   Example: If X = [0 1 2
%                    3 4 5]
%
%   then mean(X,1) is [1.5 2.5 3.5] and mean(X,2) is [1
%                                                     4]
%
%   Class support for input X:
%      float: double, single
%
%   See also MEDIAN, STD, MIN, MAX, VAR, COV, MODE.

%   Copyright 1984-2005 The MathWorks, Inc. 
%   $Revision: 5.17.4.3 $  $Date: 2005/05/31 16:30:46 $

if nargin==1, 
  % Determine which dimension SUM will use
  dim = min(find(size(x)~=1));
  if isempty(dim), dim = 1; end

  y = sum(x)/size(x,dim);
else
  y = sum(x,dim)/size(x,dim);
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use this:

```
function echo(mfile)
    filename=which(mfile);
    if isempty(filename)
        fprintf('Invalid input - check you are inputting a string.');
        return;
    end
    fid=fopen(filename,'r');
    if (fid<0)
        fprintf('Couldn''t open file.');
    end
    file=fread(fid,Inf);
    fclose(fid);
    fprintf('%s',file);
end
```

This will open a file, read it, and print it. Note that you need to provide the input as a string, i.e. with single quotes around it, and need to have '.m' at the end:

```
echo('fread.m')
```

Not

```
echo(fread.m) % This won't work
echo('fread') % This won't work
```

Comment: @Shai  : I just tried it now   . excellent too !  so the function of HughNolan is already exists ....

Answer (score 1):

Just for completeness, there's also [`dbtype`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/dbtype.html) which prepends line numbers.