# Input arguments error

Tags: matlab, function, input

In order to get to know MATLAB a little bit better, I tried to run the following code which I found on a help file of MATLAB:

```
function F = myfun(x,c)
   F = [ 2*x(1) - exp(c*x(1))
        -x(1) - exp(c*x(2))
        x(1) - x(2) ];

   c = -1; % define parameter first
   x = lsqnonlin(@(x) myfun(x,c),[1;1])
```

However, I get the following error :

```
Error using F (line 2)
Not enough input arguments.
```

How is this possible? The two arguments necessary ( x and c) are stated in the definition of F, right?

Hope you can help me with this ! Many thanks in advance for your replies!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you are calling it the right way?

When I save this in `myfun.m`:

```
function F = myfun(x,c)
   F = [ 2*x(1) - exp(c*x(1))
        -x(1) - exp(c*x(2))
        x(1) - x(2) ];
end
```

And write this in the command window, it works:

```
c = -1; % define parameter first
x = lsqnonlin(@(x) myfun(x,c),[1;1])

x =  
    0.2983
    0.6960
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried to run the whole script at once. When I, like you showed me, first save the myfun.m part and then write the c and x statements in the command window, it works fluently.

Is it possible to include both the function and the c and x statement in just one script? (sorry for this MatLab beginner level question )

Comment: @Justinnl: You could even do it in a single statement if you _really_ want, `x = lsqnonlin(@(x) [ 2*x(1) - exp(c*x(1)); -x(1) - exp(c*x(2)); x(1) - x(2) ],[1;1])`, but I would stick with having `myfun` in a separate file. Check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5363397/in-matlab-can-i-have-a-script-and-a-function-definition-in-the-same-file), for some extra information regarding functions inside scripts.

Comment: @ Robert P : thank you very much for the information. I am trying to get to know the matlab principles and you really helped me out with the functions topic. I will have a look at the question for the extra information. Thanks !

Answer (score -3):

Put triple dot at the end of each incomplete line. And you don't need that square bracket.

```
    F = 2*x(1) - exp(c*x(1)) ...
        -x(1) - exp(c*x(2)) ...
        x(1) - x(2);
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. However, the same error is displayed after I processed the suggested improvements (which might be wrong...) ; what could be the problem ?

Comment: Sorry, I ran out of ideas.