# Error in matlab function definition

Tags: matlab

Here is my code that i tried to write a matlab function that takes a matrix as input and returned a matrix as output.

```
a=[ 1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9];
function [s]= try_1(a)
  %takes a matrix as a input
   display(' data matrix');
   disp(a);
   disp('dimension of the matrix');
   [m n]= size(a); %calculate the dimension of data matrix
   s = mean(a);
end
```

Comment: what is the error you got?

Comment: error is "Function definitions are not permitted in this context."

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5363397/in-matlab-can-i-have-a-script-and-a-function-definition-in-the-same-file) might help

Comment: sorry to say that i don't understand what's wrong in this code. i can't run it. as far i know my function declaration is correct. but the error  message is  " Function definitions are not permitted in this context."

Comment: Thank you .. i find out my fault.. that is the line 1.. thanks @Santhan Salai

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Explain clearly where you execute the above code ? 
if you execute in command prompt don't use function. code likes this

```
  a=[ 1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9];
  %takes a matrix as a input
   display(' data matrix');
   disp(a);
   disp('dimension of the matrix');
   [m n]= size(a); %calculate the dimension of data matrix
   s = mean(a);
```

or if you are not using command prompt then put the value **"a"** in another function and call the **try_1** function  from new function you created. code like this

```
function parent()
a=[ 1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9];
s= try_1(a)
end  

function [s]= try_1(a)
      %takes a matrix as a input
       display(' data matrix');
       disp(a);
       disp('dimension of the matrix');
       [m n]= size(a); %calculate the dimension of data matrix
       s = mean(a);
end
```

or assign then value inside the **try_1** function . code like this

```
function [s]= try_1(a)
a=[ 1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9];
  %takes a matrix as a input
   display(' data matrix');
   disp(a);
   disp('dimension of the matrix');
   [m n]= size(a); %calculate the dimension of data matrix
   s = mean(a);
end
```

Comment: It would actually be nice if you explained **why** the OP is getting the error.  All you're doing is telling them what they should do instead.

Comment: OP ask question what is the wrong in code ? but OP not ask why ?

Comment: Yeah... **what's** wrong with the code?  You didn't tell them what was wrong.  You just told them to do what you said in your code.  Look at the accepted answer.  It clearly explains what is wrong, and also how to fix it.  You just give a bunch of things to do, but don't explain **why** you're supposed to do it.

Comment: ok i got it next time i will give correct things with correct flow . any way very thanks for point out my mistake

Answer (score 3):

You cannnot define a function inside a script. MATLAB assumes your file is a script, because it starts with `a=[ 1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9];` - i.e. by defining a variable. MATLAB thus assumes a series of instructions is following and throws an error when it sees the function definition.

You also have to distinguish function *definitions* and function *calls*. With your code above, i.e.

```
function s = try_1(a)
...
end
```

you define what the function does (function *definition*), but you do *not* call it yet, i.e. nothing happens. For something to happen, you will have to call it by

```
a=[ 1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9];
s = try_1(a);
```

in a script or in the workspace.

About file names and what to put in each file: Functions are identified by their filename in MATLAB. It is absolutely necessary to have the function `try_1()`  in a file called `try_1.m`. And this file can not contain anything else. The `a=[ 1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9];` and function *calls*  belong in a separate script (or to test the behavior simply type it in the command window).