# How could a function be included in a script matlab r2016b?

Tags: matlab

Matlab r2016b allows for functions to be embedded in scripts. I am trying to run this script, but an error occurs, and I do not know what rules I am breaking. Here is the script:

```
clear
clc

out=nestedvol(2) 

function outvol=nestedvol(l)
outvol=2*l
end

x=4   %this line does not work.
```

This question continues off of [In MATLAB, can I have a script and a function definition in the same file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5363397/in-matlab-can-i-have-a-script-and-a-function-definition-in-the-same-file)

How could I get a script to continue after the embedded function ends? Would an anonymous function be appropriate for this?

The reason I ask this is because I make review scripts for chapters of the matlab book I am reading, so it would be nice to section areas of the code off. It seems like if any function is not included, ctrl enter does not work.

Comment: Read the help: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/local-functions-in-scripts.html  Local functions in scripts go at the end of the script, as indicated by the line that reads *You can add local functions in any order, as long as they all appear after the rest of the script code.*

Comment: An anonymous function would, of course, work just fine.

Comment: @nkjt I checked that before, but missed the part you pointed out.