# Calling local functions from command line

Tags: matlab, scope, function-pointers

I have a [local function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/local-functions.html) defined in an m-file. For example:

```
% begining of public_function.m file
function fh = public_function( )
%
% do some computation...

fh = @local_function; % return function handle to local function defined below

function y = local_function( x )
% 
% a local function inside public_function.m file
% 

% some manipulation on x
y = x;

% end of public_function.m file NOTE THAT local_function is NOT nested
```

Now, I would like to call `local_function` from command line (and not from `public_function`). I was able to do so using the function handle returned from `public_function`:

```
>> fh = public_function(); % got handle to local_function
>> y = fh( x ); % calling the local function from command line :-)
```

My question:
Is there any other way (apart from explicitly pass the function handle) to call local function from command line (or other m-file/functions)?

More precisely, I want a method to access any local function in a file (provided that I know its name). So, if I have `public_function.m` file (and function) and I *know* that `local_function` is local to that file, is there a way to access `local_function` from command line ?

Comment: You can pass the name of the sub-function as an argument of the main function. See the second example: http://www.mathworks.de/support/solutions/en/data/1-19LN6/?solution=1-19LN6

Comment: Did you check mklib at the matlab fileexchange? It automatically creates  handles to any local function in a file you list as function argument: http://www.mathworks.de/matlabcentral/fileexchange/7597-mklib-a-pedestrian-function-library-loader-generator

Comment: A better question is why you're making the function a local function if you have a pressing need to call it from outside of an m-file. The idea of making something a local function is to limit its scope. Perhaps you should put it in its own m-file, or make it a private function. I suggest taking a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3569933/52738) for more info.

Comment: I don't think is an unreasonable thing to want. If a function f is used by only 1 other function, then it lives as a local function to have its scope limited. The problem here is that if f is used by n > 1 other functions, then it must live in a global namespace. For large projects, this is clearly untenable of a solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The official documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/local-functions.html) says that:

> ... you cannot call a local function from the command line or from functions in other files.

According to this, you must pass its handle to the caller in order to allow invoking it indirectly outside its m-file. I believe that there is no documented sensible way to access local functions otherwise.

Oddly though, you can still do this with `help`:

```
help public_function>local_function
```

Comment: I am quite hoping on fishing some undocumented way to work around this "you cannot call a local function..." something along the lines of the `help` behavior...

Comment: @Shai Yeah, me too. Even though I posted this answer, I'm still looking.

Comment: @Shai: maybe you can add what you are trying to achieve in the end? Are you looking for a way to access any local function in arbitrary files, or do you want a "master function" with lots of sub-functions for everyday use?