# How to call internal function of a .m from the command prompt?

Tags: matlab, matlab-deployment

Here is the problem: I have a .m file to test in which there is a main function and several internal functions called by the main one.

How can I call this internal function (to test them), from the console?

example:

```
function main
   function_1;
   function_1;
end

function_1
disp('this is');
end

function_2
  disp(' an example');
end
```

How can I test it directly from the console?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Matlab: calling local functions from command line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15461157/matlab-calling-local-functions-from-command-line)

Comment: If your local functions are so involved as to require their own separate unit tests, perhaps there is reason to place them in their own separate files, maybe as private functions? You may find [this somewhat related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3569933/52738) helpful.

Comment: The other answer referenced above by H.Muster is very similar, but my answer introduces the useful `localfunctions` command which seems to be built for this purpose.  I wonder if it has always been in MATLAB.  I don't remember always seeing it in the docs.

Answer (score 2):

According to `help function` (see also the [online doc](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/function.html)):

> Subfunctions are not visible outside the file where they are defined.

So you need a *breakpoint*, which will allow you to access the internal function as if you were doing it from within the .m file:

1. Set a breakpoint at some point within the main function of the .m file
2. Run the .m file
3. When the `K>>` prompt appears, you can call the internal function from the console.

Answer (score 2):

You actually **can** use an [internal (local) function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/local-functions.html) outside of the M file in which it is defined, if you have it's handle. For example, the following function returns the handles to all the subfunctions with [the `localfunctions` command](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/localfunctions.html),

```
% internalHandlesTest.m
function [out,hl] = internalHandlesTest(in)

out = subfun1(in);

% hl = @subfun1; % just to get one internal function handle
hl = localfunctions; % to get all internal function handles

end

function subout = subfun1(subin)
% still internalHandlesTest.m
fprintf('You are using internalHandlesTest>subfun1!\n');
subout = subin;
end

function subfun2()
% still internalHandlesTest.m
fprintf('You are using internalHandlesTest>subfun2!\n');
end
```

Let's try it:

```
>> [out,hl] = internalHandlesTest(0);
You are using internalHandlesTest>subfun1!
>> disp(hl)
    @subfun1
    @subfun2
>> hl{1}(1)
You are using internalHandlesTest>subfun1!
ans =
     1
>> hl{2}()
You are using internalHandlesTest>subfun2!
>>
```

So, we can use internal functions outside of the M file.  These functions are of type `scopedfunctions`, and we are able to do this because MATLAB keeps track of it's `parentage` and the source file.  See the output of [the `functions` command](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/functions.html) on these handles:

```
>> functions(hl{1})
ans = 
     function: 'subfun1'
         type: 'scopedfunction'
         file: 'E:\Users\jchappelow\Documents\MATLAB\internalHandlesTest.m'
    parentage: {'subfun1'  'internalHandlesTest'}
```

Of course, you can see the help for internal functions quite easily:

```
>> help internalHandlesTest>subfun1
  still internalHandlesTest.m
```

But to run local functions, you need to get a function handle, which can only be obtained via an output argument of the canonical function.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can create package if it fits in your design and keep all functions there and call them from that package. This article might hep you:
http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/matlab_oop/scoping-classes-with-packages.html

Comment: Thanks but this is not what I need... I need to test a Matlab code using unit test and this Matlab code is made up of several functions.

I need to test functions and subfunctions...

example:

function main
   function_1;
   function_1;
end

function_1
disp('this is');
end

function_2
  disp(' an example');
end