# Matlab equivalent to C header file

Tags: matlab

Gave up on looking for this in the web... How can I do the following in Matlab:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% library.m
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

function do_this()
% ...
end

function do_that()
% ...
end

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% foo.m
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

function foo()   

for i = 1:100
    do_this();
end
do_that();

end
```

My question again: how can I create a library of functions that are organized within one file, and that could be called from other functions/scripts?

Comment: I don't think you can.  Please check out the link [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3569933/is-it-possible-to-define-more-than-one-function-per-file-in-matlab) which is similar to your question.  One of the solutions is to create a class with the static methods that could be your `do_this` and `do_that`.

Comment: @GeoffHayes is right.  The only thing I can possibly think of is if you encapsulate these methods into a class.  Then, you could create instances of this class and call those methods at will.

Comment: Side note: You can also look to [packages](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/scoping-classes-with-packages.html#brf3g8k), but that just about avoiding name collisions, not about having multiple functions in one file (@GeoffHayes solution using static methods is probably the only way).

Comment: Side note: You can have [nested functions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/nested-functions.html). But this would only allow you to call the main function from the outside.