# MATLAB: Is it best to use individual file functions, anonymous functions, or single file subfunctions?

Tags: matlab, coding-style

I am trying to develop good coding practices while developing in MATLAB. I have a strong background in C and x86, but I feel restricted in my ability to do identical coding convention in MATLAB.

Comment: Most common case is one function per file, but it really depends on context.

Comment: I upvoted out of Matlab frustration, I share your pain. [Though this question has already been answered quite well](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3569933). Consider deleting your question if that answer works.

Comment: Though this is maybe not a duplicate question, the linked question by @kmac gives you all you need to know. Apart from anonymous functions, which are just great for something small which needs to be done multiple times within a file or just for the sake of readability. They can't be seen outside a file as they are basically a variable. And they limit you to *single output one liners*.

Comment: @thewaywewalk Depending on the function used, anonymous functions [can have multiple outputs](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2007/01/31/multiple-outputs/)

Comment: @kmac that is a very helpful resource, but not completely the answer I am looking for. As thewaywewalk cited with readability, this is the other piece to the answer I am looking for.