# Matlab function handle optimizing

Tags: matlab, function-handle

I have a function handle in Matlab like this

`fhandle = @(A) max(1-2*A,0).*(2*A.^5+2*A + 1)`

Where `A` is typically a matrix. I perform this quite a few times and it is slowing down the computation. It is possible to keep it as a function handle (so I don't have to rewrite code) but to compute `2*A` once and for all and then apply it the three times?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using it in a loop? Does `A` change every time or is it fixed?

Answer (score 6):

First, one small quibble: you're not computing `2*A` 3 times. You're computing it twice and computing `2*A.^5` once. Note that [power operators take precedence over multiplication operators](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f0-40063.html#f0-38155). You *could* break it up as `(2*A).*A.^4`, but you might not be saving yourself much work.

Since you are limited to a single expression inside an [anonymous function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f4-70115.html), there are no particularly clean or efficient ways I can think of to precompute `2*A` in this case. Instead, you could just move the multiplicative factors outside the parentheses to reduce the amount of multiplications you perform. You can rewrite your equation as follows:

```
fhandle = @(A) 4.*max(0.5 - A,0).*(A.^5 + A + 0.5);
```

Note that your operation using [MAX](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/max.html) will be unaffected by moving the factor of 2 outside the operation, since it is simply setting all the negative elements of `1-2*A` to zero. The factors of 2 removed from each part of the equation result in a single factor of 4 multiplying the result, thus halving the number of element-wise multiplications you perform.

Even though you mention not wanting to rewrite the code, you might want to consider using a [function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f4-39629.html) or [subfunction](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f4-70666.html) instead of an anonymous function if efficiency is key. Based on the results shown in [this answer to a question about OOP timing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1693429/matlab-oop-is-it-slow-or-am-i-doing-something-wrong/1745686#1745686), it appears that anonymous functions may have more overhead. And for such a short function, rewriting it wouldn't be that much work.