# Performance issue using enumerations

Tags: matlab, enums

I have a for loop in MATLAB (I know, I know - I should be using vectorization but in this particular case it just makes sense to loop) which replaces certain elements of a vector with a value. This vector is a custom enumeration datatype. The replacement is very slow compared to a similar approach with built-in datatypes (see simple test results below). I'd expect some difference but three orders of magnitude seems high. *Is this a know issue?*

To recreate the issue create the following enumeration:

```
classdef MyEnum

    enumeration
        TRUE
        FALSE
        INDETERMINATE
    end

end
```

Initialize a vector and do some replacement in a loop:

```
>> v = repmat(MyEnum.TRUE, 100000, 1);
>> tic; for ii = 1:length(v); v(ii) = MyEnum.FALSE; end; toc;
Elapsed time is 0.824617 seconds.
```

Compare this with a similar approach using a built-in type:

```
>> v = true(100000, 1);
>> tic; for ii = 1:length(v); v(ii) = false; end; toc;
Elapsed time is 0.000950 seconds.
```

Comment: *I know, I know - I should be using vectorization* ... Not necessarily true with the improvements in recent versions of Matlab.

Comment: @High Performance Mark - Can you give a link to some info on these improvements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are adding a method call at each iteration, which in general is a slow operation. In addition, OOP in Matlab is especially inefficient as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1693429/is-matlab-oop-slow-or-am-i-doing-something-wrong). Read the SO question, there are some interesting details including discussion of performance speedups in newer Matlab versions.

Comment: MyEnum.FALSE adds a method call? Can you explain this further?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, it's likely to be the `MyEnum.FALSE` piece that's slow. Whenever I've needed to do anything similar, I extract the enum value first, i.e.

```
falseVal = MyEnum.FALSE; for ii = 1:N, v(ii) = falseVal; end
```

That might help at least in part.

Comment: I was thinking along the same lines. This improved it slightly but still a large performance difference between using native and custom types.