# Matlab object takes a large space in a .mat file

Tags: matlab

I have an object from some class I wrote in Matlab. When I use "whos" command to determine its size, it is roughly 720,000 Bytes. When I save it in a .mat file it take roughly 75MB. What is going on?

Is there an efficient way of saving and loading an object in Matlab?

EDIT: Here is a list of the properties and their size

```
            CT_COL: 2
            p: 5
            d: 10
            n: 37
            N: 20
          idx: [20x1 double]
           Am: [4-D double]
            X: [4-D double]
            y: [37x1 double]
        KGram: [20x20 double]
       reWave: []
          rpw: 2
         grps: [1x37 double]
        exIDX: [1 4 5 6 13]
          nCV: 100
        prIDX: [100x6 double]
        trIDX: [100x26 double]
            U: [5x100 double]
            V: [10x100 double]
            B: [20x100 double]
         Yhat: [37x100 double]
          Lam: [100x1 double]
    peakRatio: [37x1 double]
```

Both Am and X are 20x10x5x37 arrays (of double)

By the way, the property "reWave" used to hold the handle of a method of another object. I thought that might not be a good idea (and might be causing this), so I have removed any mention of it from the class definition. But it seems to somehow appear in the set of properties. (Even after I have issued "clear classes".)

EDIT2: I am using the command  `save('uvXbMod1.mat','ob')`  to save just the object. Here comes the puzzling: When I use the command  `whos -file uvXbMod1.mat`  to see what is saved inside the file, it shows

```
Name      Size             Bytes   Class        Attributes

ob        1x1              680512  uvXbModel
```

(This is for another instance, not the one mentioned above.) What else is put in the .mat file that makes it that big?

EDIT3: OK... The problem seemed to be two inline function handles I stored in two protected properties. Just these two,  `@(X) median(abs(X),2)` and  `@median` . The handles themselves were just a few bytes in size, and I assumed that since they are inline functions, they should just be stored  along with their one-line definitions as text (?). But apparently that does not happen, it causes a huge amount of other things to be stored along (which doesn't seem that strange after the fact ...)

Comment: Could you be a little more descriptive about the object? What is its type and what are its dimensions?

Comment: I have edited the post with a list of properties.

Comment: That object definitely seems consistent with your report of 720 kB or so.  Is it possible you're saving the entire workspace and not just this object?

Comment: What is the command you are using for the save? It should be something like `save('myfile.mat', 'myobject')`. If you leave off the second parameter, then, as @RyanJ.Smith suggested, you would be saving your entire workspace - which could easily be 75M. A .mat file is typically much smaller than the size reported by `whos` since it's compressed.

Comment: How big are those 4D arrays? :)

Comment: @Floris, I am using the command you mentioned (not saving the entire workspace, just that one variable)

Comment: @Ryan, I am not saving the entire workspace,and that is the thing that is puzzling me.

Comment: @Rody, those are 20 x 10 x 5 x 37.

Comment: I should also mention that there are some protected properties that are not showing, but those are empty in the instance that I am saving.

Comment: I am afraid that without being able to reproduce the issue we won't be of much help. I would recommend either to share the code or contact TMW support to retain privacy.

Comment: Does the class have a `saveobj` method? Private properties? Superclasses?

Comment: OK so what if you ZIP the file? To what size does it compress?

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis - that ought not to help. From -v7 (R7.0) onwards `.mat` is a compressed format. But yes, so "cruft" must be carried along. Just to be completely sure - can you (a) save to a new file (in case you have some `-append` option), and (b) tell us _exactly_ how you determined the file size? Clutching as straws now...

Comment: @Andrew, not it does not have saveobj, but thanks for that pointing out.

Comment: Thanks everyone for their contribution. I have figured out what was going on and updated my post.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I suggest you post this as an "answer" to your question; you will be able to "accept" it after a certain period and it will help others with the same problem find your solution!

Comment: That's not actually an "inline" function, that's an "anonymous" function. Inline functions are created with the `inline()` function, and they are stored as strings. Anonymous functions like this one here are stored as p-code like normal Matlab functions.

Comment: And they grab values. I think what happens is they store a snapshot of their entire enclosing workspace (all variable values) with them. The way Matlab defines it, inline functions keep a copy of each variable they reference in the enclosing workspace. But, since Matlab is so dynamic, with stuff like `eval`, the interpreter can't tell what variables an arbitrary expression will reference. So I think it just captures all of them as a conservative shortcut. (Though one would think they could optimize simple cases like yours here, which doesn't reference *any* variables or use `eval`.)

Comment: (And I don't mean to be picky here, just want to let you know what's going on. Good find!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the issue that I have found with my code:
The problem was two <strike>inline</strike> anonymous function handles I stored in two protected properties. Just these two, `@(X) median(abs(X),2)` and `@median`.

The handles themselves were just a few bytes in size, and I assumed that since they are  <strike>inline</strike> anonymous functions, they should just be stored along with their one-line definitions as text. But apparently that does not happen, and it causes a huge amount of other things to be stored along.

Comment: Again, not to be nitpicky, but these are "anonymous", not "inline" functions, and the distinction matters with respect to this topic: anonymous functions will capture copies of the workspace as happened to you, and inline functions will not. But +1 regardless.

Comment: Thanks, fixed. I am wondering how they compare in terms of speed. I remember seeing a post comparing the speed for various function calls in Matlab ... .

Comment: You mean this post? ;) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1693429/is-matlab-oop-slow-or-am-i-doing-something-wrong/1745686#1745686.

I don't know how inline functions compare for performance. IIRC they used to be slow, but they might be compiled down in to p-code like anonymous functions now. I don't know that they're actually stored as text internally and evaluated each time; just that you provide them as text and they don't capture values.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful link ... I guess that was it.