# How to speed up table-retrieval with MATLAB and JDBC?

Tags: sql, matlab, postgresql, jdbc, resultset

I am accessing a PostGreSQL 8.4 database with JDBC called by MATLAB.
The tables I am interested in basically consist of various columns of different datatypes. They are selected through their time-stamps.

Since I want to retrieve big amounts of data I am looking for a way of making the request faster than it is right now.

---

What I am doing at the moment is the following:
First I establish a connection to the database and call it `DBConn`. Next step would be to prepare a Select-Statement and execute it:

```
QUERYSTRING = ['SELECT * FROM ' TABLENAME '...
WHERE ts BETWEEN ''' TIMESTART ''' AND ''' TIMEEND ''''];

QUERY = DBConn.prepareStatement(QUERYSTRING);
RESULTSET = QUERY.executeQuery();
```

Then I store the columntypes in variable COLTYPE (1 for `FLOAT`, -1 for `BOOLEAN` and 0 for the rest - nearly all columns contain `FLOAT`). Next step is to process every row, column by column, and retrieve the data by the corresponding methods. `FNAMES` contains the fieldnames of the table.

```
m=0; % Variable containing rownumber

while RESULTSET.next()
  m = m+1;

  for n = 1:length(FNAMES)

    if COLTYPE(n)==1 % Columntype is a FLOAT
      DATA{1}.(FNAMES{n})(m,1) = RESULTSET.getDouble(n);
    elseif COLTYPE(n)==-1 % Columntype is a BOOLEAN
      DATA{1}.(FNAMES{n})(m,1) = RESULTSET.getBoolean(n);
    else
      DATA{1}.(FNAMES{n}){m,1} = char(RESULTSET.getString(n));
    end

  end

end
```

When I am done with my request I close the statement and the connection.

I don´t have the MATLAB database toolbox so I am looking for solutions without it.

---

I understand that it is very ineffective to request the data of every single field. Still, I failed on finding a way to get more data at once - for example multiple rows of the same column. Is there any way to do so? Do you have other suggestions of speeding the request up?

Comment: Since I am still a new user I am happy about any comment on how to improve my question and make it easier to answer. Any other reason limiting interest in the question and in answering it is also welcome.

Comment: Check [exec()](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/database/ug/exec.html) and [fetch()](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/database/ug/fetch.html). I get 17k rows in 6 seconds from a MySQL db using  JDBC. Consider also using `'DataReturnFormat'`, `'Dataset'` or `'Table'`, see [setdbprefs()](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/database/ug/setdbprefs.html). If this solves, I'll make it a proper answer.

Comment: @OlegKomarov These are all part of the database toolbox. I use open alternatives for `exec()` and `fetch` that do exactly what I described in the questions. I cannot rely on the database toolbox.

Comment: You should include this info in your question. Also, you mean you cannot rely on the db toolbox, because you don't have it?

Comment: @OlegKomarov exactly. I don´t have, so I have to use different ways. Sorry I didn´t mention that directly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Summary

To speed this up, push the loops, and then your column datatype conversion, down in to the Java layer, using the Database Toolbox or custom Java code. The Matlab-to-Java method call overhead is probably what's killing you, and there's no way of doing block fetches (multiple rows in one call) with plain JDBC. Make sure the knobs on the JDBC driver you're using are set appropriately. And then optimize the transfer of expensive column data types like strings and dates.

(NB: I haven't done this with Postgres, but have with other DBMSes, and this will apply to Postgres too because most of it is about the JDBC and Matlab layers above it.)

### Details

#### Push loops down to Java to get block fetching

The most straightforward way to get this faster is to push the loops over the rows and columns down in to the Java layer, and have it return blocks of data (e.g. 100 or 1000 rows at a time) to the Matlab layer. There is substantial per-call overhead in invoking a Java method from Matlab, and looping over JDBC calls in M-code is going to incur (see [Is MATLAB OOP slow or am I doing something wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1693429/is-matlab-oop-slow-or-am-i-doing-something-wrong/1745686#1745686) - full disclosure: that's my answer). If you're calling JDBC from M-code like that, you're incurring that overhead on every single column of every row, and that's probably the majority of your execution time right now.

The JDBC API itself does not support "block cursors" like ODBC does, so you need to get that loop down in to the Java layer. Using the Database Toolbox like Oleg suggests is one way to do it, since they implement their lower-level cursor stuff in Java. (Probably for precisely this reason.) But if you can't have a database toolbox dependency, you can just write your own thin Java layer to do so, and call that from your M-code. (Probably through a Matlab class that is coupled to your custom Java code and knows how to interact with it.) Make the Java code and Matlab code share a block size, buffer up the whole block on the Java side, using primitive arrays instead of object arrays for column buffers wherever possible, and have your M-code fetch the result set in batches, buffering those blocks in cell arrays of *primitive* column arrays, and then concatenate them together.

Pseudocode for the Matlab layer:

```
colBufs = repmat( {{}}, [1 nCols] );
while (cursor.hasMore())
    cursor.fetchBlock();
    for iCol = 1:nCols
        colBufs{iCol}{end+1} = cursor.getBlock(iCol); % should come back as primitive
    end
end
for iCol = 1:nCols
    colResults{iCol} = cat(2, colBufs{iCol}{:});
end
```

#### Twiddle JDBC DBMS driver knobs

Make sure your code exposes the DBMS-specific JDBC connection parameters to your M-code layer, and use them. Read the doco for your specific DBMS and fiddle with them appropriately. For example, Oracle's JDBC driver defaults to setting the default fetch buffer size (the one inside their JDBC driver, not the one you're building) to about 10 rows, which is way too small for typical data analysis set sizes. (It incurs a network round trip to the db every time the buffer fills.) Simply setting it to 1,000 or 10,000 rows is like turning on the "Go Fast" switch that had shipped set to "off". Benchmark your speed with sample data sets and graph the results to pick appropriate settings.

#### Optimize column datatype transfer

In addition to giving you block fetch functionality, writing custom Java code opens up the possibility of doing optimized type conversion for particular column types. After you've got the per-row and per-cell Java call overhead handled, your bottlenecks are probably going to be in date parsing and passing strings back from Java to Matlab. Push the date parsing down in to Java by having it convert SQL date types to Matlab `datenum`s (as Java doubles, with a column type indicator) as they're being buffered, maybe using a cache to avoid recalculation of repeated dates in the same set. (Watch out for `TimeZone` issues. Consider Joda-Time.) Convert any `BigDecimal`s to `double` on the Java side. And cellstrs are a big bottleneck - a single char column could swamp the cost of several float columns. Return narrow CHAR columns as 2-d chars instead of cellstrs if you can (by returning a big Java `char[]` and then using `reshape()`), converting to `cellstr` on the Matlab side if necessary. (Returning a Java `String[]`converts to `cellstr` less efficiently.) And you can optimize the retrieval of low-cardinality character columns by passing them back as "symbols" - on the Java side, build up a list of the unique string values and map them to numeric codes, and return the strings as an primitive array of numeric codes along with that map of number -> string; convert the distinct strings to cellstr on the Matlab side and then use indexing to expand it to the full array. This will be faster and save you a lot of memory, too, since the copy-on-write optimization will reuse the same primitive char data for repeated string values. Or convert them to `categorical` or `ordinal` objects instead of cellstrs, if appropriate. This symbol optimization could be a *big* win if you use a lot of character data and have large result sets, because then your string columns transfer at about primitive numeric speed, which is substantially faster, and it reduces cellstr's typical memory fragmentation. (Database Toolbox may support some of this stuff now, too. I haven't actually used it in a couple years.)

After that, depending on your DBMS, you could squeeze out a bit more speed by including mappings for all the numeric column type variants your DBMS supports to appropriate numeric types in Matlab, and experimenting with using them in your schema or doing conversions inside your SQL query. For example, Oracle's `BINARY_DOUBLE` can be a bit faster than their normal `NUMERIC` on a full trip through a db/Matlab stack like this. YMMV.

You could consider optimizing your schema for this use case by replacing string and date columns with cheaper numeric identifiers, possibly as foreign keys to separate lookup tables to resolve them to the original strings and dates. Lookups could be cached client-side with enough schema knowledge.

If you want to go crazy, you can use multithreading at the Java level to have it asynchronously prefetch and parse the next block of results on separate Java worker thread(s), possibly parallelizing per-column date and string processing if you have a large cursor block size, while you're doing the M-code level processing for the previous block. This really bumps up the difficulty though, and ideally is a small performance win because you've already pushed the expensive data processing down in to the Java layer. Save this for last. And check the JDBC driver doco; it may already effectively be doing this for you.

#### Miscellaneous

If you're not willing to write custom Java code, you can still get some speedup by changing the syntax of the Java method calls from `obj.method(...)` to `method(obj, ...)`. E.g. `getDouble(RESULTSET, n)`. It's just a weird Matlab OOP quirk. But this won't be much of a win because you're still paying for the Java/Matlab data conversion on each call.

Also, consider changing your code so you can use `?` placeholders and bound parameters in your SQL queries, instead of interpolating strings as SQL literals. If you're doing a custom Java layer, defining your own @connection and @preparedstatement M-code classes is a decent way to do this. So it looks like this.

```
QUERYSTRING = ['SELECT * FROM ' TABLENAME ' WHERE ts BETWEEN ? AND ?'];
query = conn.prepare(QUERYSTRING);
rslt = query.exec(startTime, endTime);
```

This will give you better type safety and more readable code, and may also cut down on the server-side overhead of query parsing. This won't give you much speed-up in a scenario with just a few clients, but it'll make coding easier.

Profile and test your code regularly (at both the M-code and Java level) to make sure your bottlenecks are where you think they are, and to see if there are parameters that need to be adjusted based on your data set size, both in terms of row counts and column counts and types. I also like to build in some instrumentation and logging at both the Matlab and Java layer so you can easily get performance measurements (e.g. have it summarize how much time it spent parsing different column types, how much in the Java layer and how much in the Matlab layer, and how much waiting on the server's responses (probably not much due to pipelining, but you never know)). If your DBMS exposes its internal instrumentation, maybe pull that in too, so you can see where you're spending your server-side time.

Comment: Wow. Thanks for that answer, a lot to understand and learn for me. I will work it through next week and try as much as I can although I might have to decuple my Java knowledge for this. Thank you very much!

Comment: I don´t understand this part:
_buffering those blocks in cell arrays of primitive column arrays_ (first paragraph of **Details**).
What do you mean by _primitive column arrays_? What would nonprimitive be?

Comment: "Primitives" = Matlab `double`, `single`, `[u]int[N]` types, or (if you want to stretch the definition) 2D `char` arrays representing strings. Nonprimitives = `struct`s, `cellstr`s, `cell`s, Matlab objects, Java objects, nested cells, or anything else. Basically, primitives are the built-in Matlab datatypes that can be represented as contiguous byte arrays in memory wrapped in a single MxArray, with no other layers of indirection (pointers or wrappers) involved.

Comment: You're welcome! And don't forget your Java background; half of this is knowing what Java can do efficiently vs Matlab, and how the Java types map to Matlab types.

Comment: +1 for the retrieval of data in blocks vs individual calls. This makes a significant difference in speed.

Comment: I wrote a java-programm which performs the queries, also because it will probably need also a MATLAB-independent solution later. Comes out it executes the same things at 10% of the time. Thanks for your tips, seems that they hit the nail right on the head.

Comment: Paul - could you please post your Java wrapper program to the Matlab File Exchange so that others might benefit from it as well? Place a comment here with the URL when it's ready. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It occurs to me that to speed up the query to the table, you have to remove if, for that in the JDBC ResulSetMetadata there that give you the information about the data type of the column and the same name, so you save time of if, else if

```
  ResultSetMetaData RsmD = (ResultSetMetaData) rs.getMetaData (); 

        int cols=rsMd.getColumnCount();
        
  while (rs.next) 
   for i=1 to cols
     row[i]=rs.getString(i);
```

My example is pseudocode becouse i´m not matlab programmer.

I hope you find it useful JDBC, anything let me know!

Comment: Hi @santiago92, thanks for your answer. I don´t think this will make a difference, since the better use of the different methods will make it more effective to parse the data from the DB. this will likely be more exact and faster, even with the `if` and `elseif`.