# Calling Java from Matlab is very slow

Tags: matlab, matlab-java

I'm calling a jar file from Matlab using the system function. Like this:

```
system('java -jar myfile.jar')
```

When I run the jar file directly through CLI it runs like a charm in less than 1min.

When I call it from Matlab using the system function, however, it takes around 10min to run!

Any ideas on how to solve this, or the cause of the slowness?

Comment: Maybe this from stackoverflow can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1693429/is-matlab-oop-slow-or-am-i-doing-something-wrong

Comment: Tks, but i'm not calling a java function within matlab... I'm just calling the jar with the system command, like this:

system('java -jar myfile.jar')

This call is taking 10x more than execution from CLI.

Comment: Is there much console output? If so try to pipe it to null. Forwarding this output to the matlab command prompt might be slow.

Comment: You could still try to call the Java functions in the jar directly from Matlab. It might be faster. See `javaaddpath`.

Comment: Did you try it with `!java -jar myfile.jar` ?