# a handle to shorten the name of stuct/class in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a struct with relative sophisticated data trees. for example:

```
class.data.head{1}.data2
```

What I wish to get is a variable named **data2_link** to link with address **class.data.head{1}.data2**, so that:

(1) if there is any change on **class.data.head{1}.data2**, it will automatically reflected to **data2_link** as well, and vise versa.

(2) I do not have to type the long name to access the data at **class.data.head{1}.data2**.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Matlab does not support references. The only exception is `handle` which allows references to **objects**.

To use it, `data2` must be an object with superclass `handle`, then you could simply write:

```
data2_link=class.data.head{1}.data2
```

Note that object oriented matlab [significantly slows down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1693429/is-matlab-oop-slow-or-am-i-doing-something-wrong) your code unless you use Matlab 2015b or newer.

Comment: Can you please clarify, or provide a source for, the last statement? In particular that Matlab 2015b improves performance of object oriented code.

Comment: Added the link to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

There is an extremely discouraged way to do it. you can create a function handle that evaluates the desired expression:

```
data2_link = @() evalin('caller', 'class.data.head{1}.data2')
```

Now every time you need that expression just call it using

```
>> data2_link()
```

The extra parentheses are necessary to invoke the function defined by function handle.

Comment: what is the consequence of using this approach? why it is not encouraged?

Comment: Reasons to [avoid eval](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/string-evaluation.html) are listed here. Further using `evalin('caller'..` is even worse, because it violates the common notion of a variable scope, resulting in code which is difficult to debug. Further, you can not pass this reference to functions, it will always search in the caller scope for the variable.

Comment: As a hack, this is brilliant, but although I really want to, I just can't bring myself to upvote it because I don't want to encourage someone to actually do this! But thank you for posting the answer anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Just got another idea, you could use `subsref` to access it and `subassign` to write. It is not really what I would call a reference because you still need `S`, but it probably comes as close to it as possible without using OOP.

```
S=substruct('.','data','.','head','{}',{1},'.','data2')
%previous line is the same as: S=struct('type',{'.','.','{}','.'},'subs',{'data','head',{1},'data2'})
f=subsref(class,S)
```