# How do I vectorize this?

Tags: matlab, vectorization

```
new = zeros(TR);
for i1 = 1 : TR
    for i2 = 1 : TR
        for j1 = 1 : TR
            for j2 = 1 : TR
                  new(i1, i2) = new(i1, i2) + p1(i1, j1) * p2(i2, j2) * ...
                                self.radon(ind - 1, i1, i2, j1, j2) * ...
                                current(j1, j2);
            end
        end
   end
end
```

Here size of "new", p1, p2, current is TRxTR, and radon is N_timesteps x TR x TR x TR x TR.

Essentially what I am doing here is for a fixed time step "ind" computing expectation on the previous time step "ind -1" using transition probability p1 * p2 * radon.

Thank you!

Update:

I was able to half-vectorize it as follows:

```
for i1 = 1 : TR
    for i2 = 1 : TR
        new(i1, i2) = sum(sum((p1(i1, :)' * p2(i2, :)) .* ...           
                      squeeze(self.radon(ind - 1, i1, i2, :, :)) .* current));
    end
end
```

So now it runs in 16 seconds instead of 2min. Can anybody suggest any more improvements? Thanks!

Comment: `self.radon` <- are you using matlab oop? Is this part of a class method?

Comment: yes, self.radon is just a class attribute. I will remove self to reduce confusion.

Comment: Leave it in the code. I thing that is the point where you are losing most of the performance!

Comment: how so? do you mean matlab JIT compiler cannot optimize this?

Answer (score 0):

I will interpret "how to vectorize this" as "how to make it faster", answering at least this. Unless you use matlab 2015b or newer, accessing class attributes is slow. Performance measurements [are available here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1693429/is-matlab-oop-slow-or-am-i-doing-something-wrong).

You may use a temporary variable to increase the performance:

```
radonslice=self.radon(ind - 1, :, :, :, :)
```

Then use `radonslice(1, i1, i2, j1, j2)` in your code.

Comment: Hm, your link talks about class methods, not attributes. I tried with radodslice, and it is actually slower: the whole simulation runs in 6min instead of 2min. Both times 90+% of the time is spent in these nested loops.

Comment: Sorry. Actually, there is a slight speedup with this change. I measured it wrong :)

Comment: The question is about methods, but the benchmarks contain properies as well, search for `classdef property:`

Comment: any way to speedup "squeeze"? Haha, now matlab profiler says that most of the time is spent there...

Comment: You could try to `permute` the matrix once outside the loop. `r2=permute(radon,[4,5,1,2,3])` to swap dimensions, then `r2(:,:,ind - 1, i1, i2)`