# How to overload subsref / numArgumentsFromSubscript for functions which have zero output arguments?

Tags: matlab, oop, indexing, overloading

I would like to have a class which wraps up a `containers.Map`. In addition, I want to be able use `()` indexing to access the sub-map from the parent class, for example:

```
>> map = containers.Map('Foo', 'Bar');
>> ex = Example(map);
>> ex('Foo')

ans =

Bar
```

The code for this is below, and it works well. The only problem I am having is with other methods defined on the class. According to the docs, I understand I need to override `numArgumentsFromSubscript` (somehow?) to help `nargout`. My crude attempt at simply using `numel(obj)` as I've seen mentioned online works in most cases, but not when the function you are calling has no output arguments (in which case `numel(obj) == 1 ~= 0`).

Using the example code below,

```
>> ex.outGoodbye

ans =

Goodbye
```

Great! However,

```
>> ex.sayHello
Error using Example/sayHello
Too many output arguments.

Error in Example/subsref (line 17)
                 [varargout{1:nargout}] = builtin('subsref', obj, struct);
```

How can you fix this?

```
classdef Example
    % =====================================================================
    properties
        map
    end
    % =====================================================================
    methods
        % -----------------------------------------------------------------
        function obj = Example(map)
            obj.map = map;
        end
        % -----------------------------------------------------------------
        function varargout = subsref(obj, struct)
            if strcmp(struct(1).type, '()')
                 [varargout{1:nargout}] = builtin('subsref', obj.map, struct);
            else
                 [varargout{1:nargout}] = builtin('subsref', obj, struct);
            end
        end
        % -----------------------------------------------------------------
        function n = numArgumentsFromSubscript(obj, struct, indexingContext)
            n = numel(obj); % Necessary to overload subsref - for some reason
        end
        % -----------------------------------------------------------------
        function obj = subsasgn(obj, struct, varargin)
            if strcmp(struct(1).type, '()')
                obj = builtin('subsasgn', obj.map, struct, varargin{:});
                obj = Example(obj);
            else
                obj = builtin('subsasgn', obj, struct, varargin{:});
            end
        end
        % -----------------------------------------------------------------
        function sayHello(obj)
            disp('Hello'); % nargout == 0. Does NOT work
        end
        % -----------------------------------------------------------------
        function out = outGoodbye(obj)
            out = 'Goodbye'; % nargout > 0. Works
        end
        % -----------------------------------------------------------------
    end
    % =====================================================================
end
```

Comment: Why do you need to overload `numArgumentsFromSubscript` if you're just going to return `numel(obj)`? Typically you would have some branching logic in `numArgumentsFromSubscript` otherwise you'd just rely on the built-in handling.

Comment: Because it does seem to do _something_. Without overloading `numArgumentsFromSubscript` the following example doesn't work (apologies for horrible formatting): `strct.property = 'Prop'`, `map = containers.Map('Foo', strct)`, `ex = Example(map)`, `ex('Foo').property`
`Error using Example/subsref (line 15)
Insufficient number of outputs from right hand side of equal sign to satisfy assignment.`

Comment: Ok gotcha. I'll definitely look into this. I have done a lot of overloading of `subsref` and it's really difficult to work with in general.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you so much - I really appreciate the help. I agree it seems unnecessarily complicated. I guess this is what happens when object orientation is a bolted on as an after thought...

Comment: Let me know if the answer I have provided isn't clear enough. This was definitely a fun one to investigate!

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. My preference is for the `nargout` method, and modifying `numArgumentsFromSubscript` as it just feels too spooky for me for `method(obj)` to work, but `obj.method` to break. Saying that, I can't get your example to work. For example: `K>> nargout('containers.Map>containers.Map.isKey')
Error using nargout
Not a valid MATLAB file`. Any ideas? Thank you once again

Comment: Yea that won't work for `containers.Map` like you've shown because that's not a class. It *should* work for your class `nargout('Example>Example.sayHello')` and in the snippets I have below.

Comment: Thanks but that's a little annoying as in my actual code Example is namespaced (`foo.bar.Example`, for example) - for which I can't get to seem the `nargout` trick to work :( EDIT: What may be worth mentioning, is that I have noticed if I don't overload `numArgumentsFromSubscript` and stick a breakpoint in `subsref` when calling the struct example above, `nargout` _is_ set to zero. It's just that i need the `numel(obj)` trick for other method calls. How frustrating!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109580/discussion-between-suever-and-rwb).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So digging into this a little further, you have a few options for how to get around this behavior.

## `method(obj)` Calling Convention

You could simply change the way that you're calling the class method. Instead of using the dot notation, you could simply use the standard function notation.

```
sayHello(ex)

%// vs.

ex.sayHello()
```

This will avoid calling `subsref` when calling a method. Also, this is actually the [fastest way to call a method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1745686/670206) of a class in the current iteration of MATLAB's OOP. Additionally, this would require no changes to your current code.

## Use `nargout` to determine number of method outputs

Another option is to add a special case in `subsref` or `numArgumentsFromSubscript` that looks for methods called using the dot notation. Then you can explicitly determine the number of output arguments of the method using the [following call](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/96617#answer_105968) to `nargout`.

```
nArgs = nargout('classname>classname.methodname');
```

Then you would use that rather than `numel(obj)`. This could be implemented in *either* `numArgumentsFromSubscript` *or* `subsref`.

**`numArgumentsFromSubscript`**

```
function n = numArgumentsFromSubscript(obj, struct, indexingContext)
    %// Check if we are calling obj.method
    if strcmp(struct(1).type, '.') && ...
        ischar(struct(1).subs) && ismember(struct(1).subs, methods(obj))

        %// Determine the package (if any)
        cls = class(obj);
        parts = regexp(cls, '\.', 'split');

        %// Import the package (if any) just into the namespace of this method
        if numel(parts) > 1
            import(cls);
        end

        %// Determine number of outputs for this method
        n = nargout(sprintf('%s>%s.%s', parts{[end end]}, struct(1).subs));
    else
        %// Default to numel(obj)
        n = numel(obj);
    end
end
```

**`subsref`**

```
function varargout = subsref(obj, struct)
    if strcmp(struct(1).type, '()')
         [varargout{1:nargout}] = builtin('subsref', obj.map, struct);

    %// Check if we are calling obj.method
    elseif strcmp(struct(1).type, '.') && ...
           ischar(struct(1).subs) && ismember(struct(1).subs, methods(obj))

        %// Determine the package (if any)
        cls = class(obj);
        parts = regexp(cls, '\.', 'split');

        %// Import the package (if any) just into the namespace of this method
        if numel(parts) > 1
            import(cls);
        end

        %// Determine number of outputs for this method
        nout = nargout(sprintf('%s>%s.%s', parts{[end end]}, struct(1).subs));         

        %// Call builtin subsref with this number of outputs
        [varargout{1:nout}] = builtin('subsref', obj, struct);

    else
        [varargout{1:nargout}] = builtin('subsref', obj, struct);
    end
end
```

## Summary

`subsref` is a pain and a lot of times you end up with a lot of logic to determine what is being called and you'll be right only about 80% of the time. I think that the first approach is the most straightforward, would likely be the most performant (you skip all of the checks in `subsref`) and deals better with arrays of objects.

If you really wanted to keep the `obj.method` notation, I would probably recommend changing `numArgumentsFromSubscript` (rather than `subsref`) to keep the number of output argument stuff in one place.

**Update**

Based upon your feedback that the `nargout` trick doesn't work in cases where the class is contained within a package  (`foo.bar.Example`). I have added a workaround to the above examples. The trick is to call `import('foo.bar.Example')` prior to calling `nargout('Example>Example.sayHello')`.

Comment: I don't know what I'm more taken aback by - the effort taken in producing such a detailed answer, or the unwieldiness of Matlab's OOP! Thank you for all your help

Comment: I know this is an old post, but MATLAB OOP is not much more than a clunky Mathworks afterthought. I have been assigned a project in MATLAB and all I want to do is wrap a ``Map`` and overload the ``()`` indexing operators. How is it that C++ is much easier than MATLAB?