# How to use subsref in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I use 16a. I found overloading subsref makes any function calls to an object call (). I am not sure if this is the correct use of subsref. For example,

```
classdef A < handle
    methods
        function obj = A(varargin)
        end

        function v = subsref(obj, S) %#ok<STOUT,INUSD>
            assert(false);
        end

        function c = foo(obj) %#ok<MANU>
            c = 1;
        end 
    end 
end
```

Then I god the following errors when using foo.

```
>> a = A()

a = 

  A with no properties.

>> a.foo()
Error using A/subsref (line 6)
Assertion failed.

8               assert(false);
```

If I removed subsref, it works fine. In terms of

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/subsref.html

subsref is called only when A{i}, A(i) or A.field. Since foo is a method, why is subsref still called?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is completely expected behavior, because to MATLAB, `A.field` and `A.method` *both* use the dot referencing and therefore are processed by `subsref`. The typical way of getting around this is to instead call your class methods using the standard function call rather than a dot referenced method call.

```
method(A)

%// Rather than
A.method()
```

This usage is also superior as it can operate on arrays of objects rather than only scalars. Also, it is [more performant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1693429/is-matlab-oop-slow-or-am-i-doing-something-wrong/1745686#1745686).

Comment: Can users implement a data structure like containers.Map? It has A(i) and A(i) =, and also A.length(), A.isKey(), ...

Comment: @JoeC Yes. You would have to check the inputs to `subsref` to determine if it is a method call or property access